# ubuntu 12.4 dualboot installation problem

Tags: dual-boot, wubi

I have a little problem. I want to install ubuntu with win7.
When I start wubi, this is picture that I see. If I try option full instalation ("Probna i puna instalacija" on Serbian), I see the second pic. And when I want to restart my win7, i don't see ubuntu instalation, but only win7 restart. When I tried 3rd option (if first option doesn't work), after restart, ubuntu start to loading, bud I see message:
"could not find the installation files ubuntu install custom installation...".
How to fix this problem? :)

Comment: This first option doesn't do anything except tell you to restart your computer. You should boot from your Ubuntu USB or DVD (via BIOS menu) in order to install Ubuntu. The third option, not sure, need more info on what you see.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Wubi is not longer supported since 12.04 version and actually it is practically unuseful. You can observed **Wubi.exe** into the newer iso images of Ubuntu but it doesn't work because you can not install it or Wubi crash when you try to actualize it a newer versions. It's highly recomended that you install Ubuntu in a different partition of your hard disk drive by using the new version available as iso image (CD, DVD, USB pendrive). You can use too a virtual machine in your Windows System.

Comment: okey, but i also try version 14, and it is same problem. I need something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6Ycx2K2OeY, but I can't start menu like this on video.